# mysql index merge issue

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Why mysql is not using index_merge?

Looks like my server has index_merge ON, but optimizer still not taking in to consideration.

```
optimizer switch    index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on



explain SELECT a,b FROM `zip25` WHERE b=91367 OR a=91367


id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          zip25   ALL a,b         NULL    NULL    NULL    752299  Using where
```

**[EDIT]**
Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE `zip25` (
  `a` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distance` float NOT NULL,
  KEY `a` (`a`),
  KEY `b` (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The usual way to optimize such query is using UNION (and usually it's faster even then using index_merge). However I assume that the question actually is why index_merge was not used. Can you post the table definition please?

Comment: Hi Darhazer, yes my question is why index_merge was not used. I have edited my question with table definition.

Comment: a and b are actually char and not int. The implicit casting often prevents MySQL from using index. Try putting quotes around values: `explain SELECT a,b FROM `zip25` WHERE b="91367" OR a="91367"`. Also try the same with integer types.

Comment: yeah you are correct. I overlooked it. Thanks for pointing it..

We can close this. If you could please post as answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype of the fields is char, but you are using integers in the query. What happens is implicit casting to char. It doesn't look like serious problem, but actually it prevents MySQL from using an index at all! Always mind the data types!

Change your query to:

`explain SELECT a,b FROM`zip25`WHERE b="91367" OR a="91367"`